# Trying to understand this short function

Tags: javascript

I don't think I'm fully grasping how this works (I'm a little embarrassed...by a little I mean a lot). Basically this is supposed to create a prompt and write console.log fullName with the first two letters in each prompt to be capitalized and concatenate together. Please help!

```
var fullName = ""; 
//Why does fullName have to be defined as a string? and when it's removed it doubles the value?

var name; 
var firstLetter;

var fixName = function () { 
    firstLetter = name.substring(0, 1); 
    name = firstLetter.toUpperCase() + name.substring(1);

    fullName = fullName + " " + name; 
    //what exactly is happening here under the fullName variable? What value is passing into fullName after it's being called? 
}

name = prompt("Enter your first name (all in lower case):"); 

fixName();

name = prompt("Enter your second name (all in lower case):"); 

fixName();

console.log("And your fullname is:" + fullName);
```

Comment: Just FYI: That's a pretty terrible way to do this. :)

Comment: It is one of the code year exercise to understand local and global variables, that's why it is awful.

Comment: Oh I know haha...but it's for the Codecademy classes that are online. Unfortunately this is the only site that I know of that has JS exercises. More importantly for me right now is understanding why this is working the way it does? haha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an annotated version of the function:

```
var fixName = function () { 
    // get the first letter of the string
    firstLetter = name.substring(0, 1); 

    // assign back to name the uppercased version of the first letter 
    // with the rest of the name
    name = firstLetter.toUpperCase() + name.substring(1);

    // add name onto the end of fullName
    // this will accumulate each time this function is called because
    // fullname is a global variable so it will get longer and longer each time
    // with more and more names in it
    fullName = fullName + " " + name; 
}
```

FYI, this is pretty horrible code overall.  It should be using at least some local variables and a function argument like this:

```
var fullName = ""; 

function fixName(name) { 
    var firstLetter = name.substring(0, 1); 
    fullName = fullName + " " + firstLetter.toUpperCase() + name.substring(1); 
}

fixName(prompt("Enter your first name (all in lower case):"));
fixName(prompt("Enter your second name (all in lower case):")); 
console.log("And your fullname is:" + fullName);
```

It probably shouldn't be modifying a global variable as a side effect either (probably should use a return value), but I didn't change that.

Comment: Wow...I can't believe I didn't see that. fullName adds an empty variable and a space before it gets to a filled value...and then repeats. This really IS horrible code! I'm doing my best and have been  pretty committed to learning this language but I feel like I'm not going to get any better if the exercises I find are broken/deprecated/or overall bad.

Comment: I really appreciate the quick response. This is quickly becoming my new favorite site!

Answer (score 0):

`fullName` Is first defined as an empty string, to which `name` gets concatenated once `name` has been changed to have its first letter uppercased.

In each call of `prompt`, the returned value is stored to `name`, which is also a global variable. That value of `name` is changed to proper case inside `fixName()`.

Since the function `fixName()` is called twice and `fullName` is declared in the global scope, the output of `fixName()` is added to the variable `fullName` both times.  Fist for the first name, and second for the surname (second name). In the end, `fullName` should contain `Firstname Lastname` (with an extra space at the beginning).

Answer (score 0):

The code is ugly, using so-called "side-effects", operating on global variables, without function parameters or function result. It fills `fullName` with space, capitalized first name, space, capitalized second name.

Using the following would make the global variables unnecessary.

```
function capitalized(s) {
    if (s == "") return "";
    return s.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + s.substring(1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To adapt your original code:

```
window.onload = function(){
    var names = {}, result = '';
    function fixName(input){
        return input.substr(0, 2).toUpperCase()
    }
    names.first = window.prompt("What is your first name?")
    names.last = window.prompt("What is your last name?")

    for(var n in names){
        var nameValue = names[n];
        result += fixName(nameValue)
    }
    console.log(result)
}
```

There are far better ways as others will illustrate, but this is based on what you wrote.  Happy Javascripting :)

Comment: FYI, there is no guaranteed order when iterating properties of an object like this `for(var n in names)` so this isn't guaranteed to get first name before last name.